How to implement automatic quality change in Flutter's video_player package?
I'm working on a Flutter app where I need to implement automatic quality change (adaptive streaming) in video playback using the video_player package.
I know that BetterPlayer has built-in support for adaptive quality switching, but I'm encountering compatibility issues when I use it alongside just_audio in my app. Specifically, these two packages seem to interfere with each other, causing unexpected behavior in my audio and video streams.
Since the video_player package does not natively support automatic quality change, I'm looking for a solution to handle adaptive streaming or dynamic quality change with it. Has anyone implemented a workaround or found an effective way to handle adaptive streaming in video_player?
Here's what I'd like:

Automatic quality adjustment based on network conditions.
A solution compatible with video_player, ideally without requiring Better_Player.

